# SQL query without while loop or cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having below table

```
BoxID   StockPoint  InventoryMasterID   Qty  HoldQty    AvailableQty
    7         UK                   21     3      3            0
    8         UK                   22     2      1            1
    9         UK                   23     4    NULL           4
   10         UK                   24     2    NULL           2
```

This table contains information about my stock.

Now I required to **pull total 3 Quantity out of AvailableQty and it should display a new column as PickQty which should display qty according to my RequiredQty(3) and if it is fullfilled then it should display 0 for rest of boxes.**

I want below table as out put.

```
BoxID   StockPoint  InventoryMasterID   Qty  HoldQty    AvailableQty  PickQty
 7         UK                   21         3      3            0           0
 8         UK                   22         2      1            1           1
 9         UK                   23         4    NULL           4           2
10         UK                   24         2    NULL           2           0
```

So now I will fetch all those rows where 'PickQty > 0'

I want this result without using while loop

Comment: [tag:sql-server] is a specific SQL RDBMS product which uses a dialect of sql called T-SQL. [tag:plsql] is a *different* dialect of SQL. As such, those two tags are *rarely* both applicable to a single question (unless it's about translating between dialects). Please [edit] your question to make sure that your tags actually *make sense*.

Comment: not clear why for `BoxId=9` you have `AvailableQty=4` and desired `PickQty=2`. Shouldn't `PickQty` be 1 if you pull 3 out of `AvailableQty`?

Comment: I removed the incompatible tags (Microsoft SQL Server has no PL/SQL). Please add the tag for the DBMS you are really using e.g. either `oracle` or  `sql-server`

Comment: @andrews I need to pick qty in ascending order of Box Id.  BoxId=9 have qty=4 and holdQty=null means not holding anything thats why it has all 4 quantity is availabe to pull. Thats' why I have AvailabeQty=4 in BoxID=9

Comment: Do you need to do it with one SQL statement? It seems quite involved!

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis yes I need it one statement because this logic is needed very frequently and with very large selection of rows

Comment: I described a very detailed approach; once you master it it will be easy to reuse the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting here a step-by-step answer in T-SQL; other SQL flavors can be easily derived from this I believe.

A functional demo can be found [here](http://rextester.com/PJCR30999).

**The basic query**

The basic construct for the solution is the following query:

```
    select 
    a.*, 
   (select sum(coalesce(AvailableQty,0)) 
        from stock b 
        where b.BoxID <= a.BoxID
    ) as cumulative_availability
    from stock a

BoxID   Qty HoldQty AvailableQty    cumulative_availability
7       3       3       0               0 
8       2       1       1               1   
9       4       NULL    4               5
10      2       NULL    2               7
```

**Which boxes should we take?**

Column `cumulative_availability` holds the cumulative sum of available qty for all boxes with `BoxID <= ID of current box`. From this it is easy to find how far we should go:

```
declare @demand int = 3;

declare @stopID int;

select @stopID = min(BoxID) from (
select 
    a.*, 
    (select sum(coalesce(AvailableQty,0)) 
     from stock b 
     where b.BoxID <= a.BoxID
    ) as cumulative_availability
from stock a
) temp
where cumulative_availability >= @demand;

select @stopID;
```

If `@demand = 3` this statements returns `9`, so we need to go up to the box with id = 9 to satisfy the demand. If, on the other hand, `@demand = 10`, then we don't have enough resources, and `@stopID` will be `NULL`.

**The final step**

Now it is relatively easy to compute the `PickQty` column:

```
select 
    temp.*, 
    case 
        when cumulative_availability < @demand then AvailableQty 
        else @demand - (cumulative_availability - AvailableQty)
    end 
    as PickQty
from 
(select 
    a.*, 
    (select sum(coalesce(AvailableQty,0)) 
    from stock b 
    where b.BoxID <= a.BoxID
    ) as cumulative_availability
from stock a
) temp
where BoxID <= @stopID or @stopID is null
```

The `or @stopID is null` condition guarantees that we will all the boxes if the demand is too high.

Comment: If I go with your logic, then consider the case when RequiredQty = 4 then your logic will be wrong in that case If I have the same data. In that case my pick Qty will be 1,1 which is wrong.

Comment: No I mean the same. Set demand = 4 then from Cumulative_Availability you will get Min boxId=9 and then consider the case of Pick qty

Comment: Give me a second, in the meantime you could work the process yourself and try to find the solution :-) The error must be in the last - easy - statement.

Comment: I updated the answer and the demo. In the last box we need to subtract the previously accumulated quantity, which can be computed as per the `else` part of the code.